# ESP32 AsyncWebServer

Tags: arduino, esp32

I currently trying to setup an Async Web Server on the ESP32. But unfortunately I don't get the code to run. I'm usign platform io on windows 10.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "myAP";
const char* password = "123456789";

AsyncWebServer server(80);
```

setup() and loop() are empty.
If I try to compile the code these message shows up.

```
compilation terminated.
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp: In constructor 'AsyncPrinter::AsyncPrinter(AsyncClient*, size_t)':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp:48:11: error: 'panic' was not declared in this scope
     panic(); //What should we do?
           ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp: In member function 'int AsyncPrinter::connect(IPAddress, uint16_t)':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp:71:11: error: 'panic' was not declared in this scope
     panic();
           ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp: In member function 'size_t AsyncPrinter::_sendBuffer()':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\AsyncPrinter.cpp:182:11: error: 'panic' was not declared in this scope
     panic(); // Connection should be aborted instead
           ^
                       ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCPbuffer.cpp: In member function 'size_t AsyncTCPbuffer::_handleRxBuffer(uint8_t*, size_t)':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCPbuffer.cpp:469:21: error: 'panic' was not declared in this scope
               panic(); //TODO: What action should this be ?

C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp: In member function 'bool AsyncClient::operator==(const AsyncClient&)':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp:331:66: error: 'ip_addr_t {aka struct ip_addr}' has no membec
r named 'addr'
   return (_pcb != NULL && other._pcb != NULL && (_pcb->remote_ip.addr == other._pcb->remote_ip.addr) && (_pcb->remote_port == other._pcb->remote_port));
                                                                  ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp: In member function 'void AsyncClient::_dns_found(const ip_addr*)':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp:707:31: error: 'const struct ip_addr' has no member named 'addr'
     connect(IPAddress(ipaddr->addr), _connect_port);
                               ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp: In member function 'uint32_t AsyncClient::getRemoteAddress()':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp:837:26: error: 'ip_addr_t {aka struct ip_addr}' has no member named 'addr'
   return _pcb->remote_ip.addr;
                          ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp: In member function 'uint32_t AsyncClient::getLocalAddress()':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp:849:25: error: 'ip_addr_t {aka struct ip_addr}' has no member named 'addr'
   return _pcb->local_ip.addr;
                         ^
C:\Users\x\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp: In member function 'void AsyncServer::begin()':
C:\Users\xanix\.platformio\lib\ESPAsyncTCP_ID305\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp:1122:14: error: 'ip_addr_t {aka struct ip_addr}' has no member named 'addr'
   local_addr.addr = (uint32_t) _addr;
              ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong async TCP library. The one you're using is for the ESP8266, not the ESP32.

Here's its PlatformIO library registry entry:

https://platformio.org/lib/show/305/ESPAsyncTCP

[image]

You're seeing errors because it's trying to call functions that are available on the ESP8266 and not the ESP32.

You want the AsyncTCP library:

https://platformio.org/lib/show/1826/AsyncTCP

You should update your `platformio.lib` file to include this library instead of ESPAsyncTCP. You may also need to remove the build or library directory to get rid of the old library.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped. If it did could you accept it as the answer? That will help other people with this problem find it.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, downgrading the core of PlatformIO solved for me the issue.

pip install -U "platformio<4.2.0"